# Sylius default payment gate

Tags: payment-gateway, sylius

Hi I'm in need of help setting up my sylius project.

I've overwritten the checkout process in the core bundle using a Compiler Pass so I was able to change the steps in the flow bundle scenario.

I want to skip the payment selection step and use stripe as my default gateway.

```
 public function displayAction(ProcessContextInterface $context)
    {
        $order = $this->getCurrentCart();
        $this->dispatchCheckoutEvent(SyliusCheckoutEvents::PURCHASE_INITIALIZE, $order);
        /** @var $payment PaymentInterface */
        $payment = $order->getPayments()->last();
        $captureToken = $this->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
            $payment->getMethod()->getGateway(),
            $payment,
            $context->getProcess()->getForwardRoute(),
            array('stepName' => $this->getName())
        );
        return new RedirectResponse($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
    }
```

Basically I'd like to modify this function to instantly recognise the order with a stripe payment. I've read the docs but I can't seem to work it out on my own. I know the previous step creates the payment for the order but I can't seem to find how it does so.

for those of you who'd like to help and not to look far and wide, here is a link to the original steps on github:
https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusCoreBundle/tree/master/Checkout/Step